# How to get the 'create' script from a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe df.  And lets say I wanted to share df with you guys here to allow you to easily recreate df in your own notebook.

Is there a command or function that will generate the pandas dataframe create statement? I realize that for a lot of data the statement would be quite large seeing that it must include the actual data, so a header would be ideal.

Essentially, a command that I can run on df and get something like this:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

or

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
...                    columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

I'm not sure how to even phrase this question.  Like taking a dataframe and deconstructing the top 5 rows or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We usually using `read_clipboard`

```
pd.read_clipboard()

Out[328]: 
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
```

Or If you have the df save it into dict so that we can easily convert it back to the sample we need

```
df.head(5).to_dict()
```